# How to apply for a Portugal work permit?

Tags: portugal, working-visas

I want to apply for a work permit in Portugal. Currently I’m staying in another Schengen country (Latvia). What is the procedure and requirements for applying Portugal work permit?

Comment: are you a qualified professional? What kind of job will you work?

https://imigrante.sef.pt/en/solicitar/trabalhar/

Comment: I’m professionally qualified but i heard that if go there and directly apply for work permit and search for job.

Comment: Until I know, the law changed a little bit after January. Without Visa and not from E.U, the company needs a certification to hire foreigners. Also, you will need a Promised employment contract according to the law.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a highly qualified professional, without Visa:

> The application for residence title or EU Blue Card should be
>   scheduled (via an electronic platform – to be implemented for holders
>   of residence visas) and submitted personally on a standard form signed
>   by the applicant or his/her legal representative. The application may
>   be submitted at any SEF’s directorate or regional delegation, which,
>   after proceedings and decision, will forward it to the directorate or
>   regional delegation of the applicant’s area of residence. Necessary
>   documentation as follows:
>
> - Two recent, identical photographs, in colour with blank background,    and easily identifiable (only for appointments at Odivelas, Aveiro or 
>     Braga SEF bureau)
> - Passport or any other valid travel document Valid    residence permit issued under article 61 of REPSAE, except in    applications
>     submitted under nº. 2 of article 90;
> - Evidence of sufficient means of subsistence, as per the provisions of Order    Number 1563/2007, of 11/12
> - Evidence that the applicant has adequate accommodation
> - Permission for checking criminal records (except people    under 16 years old)
>
> **Resident permit for highly qualified activity:**
>
> - Contract of employment or of services compatible with the highly qualified activity
> - Invitation letter issued by the teaching institution or statement of responsibility issued by **certified company** according to the
>     decree order of the members of the government

Source: [SEF - Work in Portugal](https://imigrante.sef.pt/en/solicitar/trabalhar/art90-1/)

Comment: I believe appointments can be made online when the expected date of arrival in Portugal is known. You should check the SEF site for that.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Isn't that what the penultimate bullet point is about? Marcel also wrote as much in a comment above.

Comment: @Relaxed Yes, he did say so, and the penultimate bullet point says so as well. The text in Article 90 is subtly different, but on balance the issue is covered. Thanks for bracing me here, I'll delete my comment.